# My wordpress php code is pulling information from database in one instance and not in other case. What is wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my plugin code, I am pulling the table id from two tables. The id is being pulled from one table but not from the other and I get errors in both instances. The queries work on mysql when I use them. any thoughts? code is below and output below that. The id gets pulled from the wp_shclass table but not the wp_shinstructor table. Any thoughts I have been staring at this for a few days and am not sure what's wrong.

```
<?php
/**
* @package pjtest
* @version 0.0
*/
/*
Plugin Name: pjtest
Plugin URI: http://tbd
Description: One page version of my code
Author: Me
Version: 0.0
Author URI:www.linkedin.com/in/tbd
*/

function shmain_admin(){
if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))  {
    wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
}

echo "Hello class";
global $wpdb;
$shrow = $wpdb->get_row("select * from wp_shclass ORDER BY classid DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);  
$shclassid = $shrow['classid'];
echo "<br> this is " . $shclassid;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
echo "<br> Hello instructor";
$shrow = $wpdb->get_row("select * from wp_shinstructor ORDER BY instructorid DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);  
$shinstructorid = $shrow['instructorid'];
echo "<br> this is " . $shinstructorid;
$wpdb->print_error();
}


function shmain_admin_action(){
add_menu_page('sh main', 'main', 'manage_options','shmain', 'shmain_admin');
}

add_action('admin_menu','shmain_admin_action');
```

And here is the output below

Hello class
this is 8

WordPress database error: []
select * from wp_shclass ORDER BY classid DESC LIMIT 1

Hello instructor
this is

WordPress database error: []
select * from wp_shinstructor ORDER BY instructorid DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: You should probably take this over to the WordPress StackExchange instead.

Comment: You should use `$wpdb->prefix` for you tables, instead of hardcoding the prefix

Comment: yes janw agreed. using $wpdb->prefix instead of wp_that is proper coding, I was trying to debug my plugin so wrote this snippet to simplyfy. any thoughts on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping and recreating the instructor table has finally worked for me. I did not need to change the code. I must have changed some default settings in MySQL when creating the table that caused the return query to break. I don't know which setting but that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor query may not be returning any results at all. Try this to find out:

```
$res = $wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM wp_shinstructor ORDER BY instructorid DESC LIMIT 1');
var_dump($res);
```

The `$wpdb->query()` function returns false on a MySQL error, otherwise it returns a count of the number of rows affected (i.e. how many records it found).

Also, if you are trying to get a single value, `$wpdb->get_var()` is probably the better option as it returns a string from a single record, like this:

```
$shclassid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT classid FROM wp_shclass ORDER BY classid DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Other than that, your code looks like it should work fine. I believe the issue lies in your queries.

Comment: Thanks when I tried using $res = $wpdb->query (...) and var_dump($res), I get the output as int (2). When I try to loop through the output I get nothing. The insturctor query works on mysql so I am not sure why it is failing to return anything.

Comment: Reg $wpdb->get_var I actually need all the columns in my query, I wrote this snippet to see what is wrong but yes $wpdb->get_var will be the way to go if I only needed one value.